# How to map domain url to another domain?

Tags: domain-mapping

I have domain ex: cards.com and
I have an web app which run's on the domain example.com

The app run's on a serverless platform. I have no IP or VM for my app

I don't want to expose example.com, I want to map this example.com to cards.com/example
can anyone let me know how map this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it by
Mapping my domain cards.com to example.com in DNS Records and had a custom API Gateway that routes it to the app that I want.